# Presenting a modal view manually from an actionsheet

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm pretty new to iOS dev, and I've been reading a ton on this problem, but still can't figure it out.

I have a button in an action sheet that is supposed to activate and present a slide-up modal that is a from/to date picking screen (it has its own controller `DatePickerViewController`. The action sheet is triggered by a button in the toolbar of a NavigationViewController's  subview ("Map of Shows" view, top left button). Graphic shows the current storyboard relationships:

[image: Navigation controller to modal relationships]

The code for this sequence looks like this:

```
// ShowsContainerController.m
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if( buttonIndex == 1 ){
        // 1. Activates from actionsheet
        [(NavigationViewController *)self.parentViewController showDateSelect];
    }
}

// NavigationViewController.m
// 2. fires up the datepicker view
-(void)showDateSelect
{
    pickerView = [[DatePickerViewController alloc] init ];

    [self presentViewController:pickerView animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// DatePickerViewController.m
// 3. Instantiation of this controller. Definitely fires nslog.
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Here");
}
```

Once "here", the screen just goes black. I assume this is because I'm not doing something right either with the instantiation of the date picker controller, or with the segue to it. All of the views in question are associated with their respective controllers in the storyboard configs. To further confuse the issue, I have a UITableViewController that I created for another screen, and just for shits and giggles, attempted to load that, and it worked fine. I then created another completely separate UIViewController, pointed it back to the controller files that control the current non-working one, and it bombs as well, so I'm thinking the issue are the header and main files for the non-working UIViewController. *ed. scratch that last note; I created a completely new header, main file and NIB for the view and it still didn't work. I don't know what the hell the deal is.*

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

*Addendum*

```
- (IBAction)showOptions:(id)sender
{
    NSString *showTypes;

    if( self.onlyShowPreferredEvents ){
        showTypes = @"\u2713 Only shows that I'll like";
    } else {
        showTypes = @"Only shows that I'll like";
    }

    _showDisplayOptionsActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event Display Settings" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: showTypes, @"Date Range", nil];

    [_showDisplayOptionsActionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];

}
```

Per the comments.

*Addendum 2*
    // All of DatePickerViewController.m

```
#import "DateRangeViewController.h"

@interface DateRangeViewController ()

@end

@implementation DateRangeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end


// All of DatePickerViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DateRangeViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Comment: Any reason why the button on the action sheet should not be connected directly to the datePickerViewController? Why do you need the datePickerViewController connected to the Nav controller ?

Comment: The Action sheet is created dynamically, so I'm not exactly sure how to make that happen. I'll update my actionsheet instantiation code.

Comment: Please see my udpated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem is that when you're using a storyboard, like I am, and you're programmatically presenting a view, you need to begin by creating a storyboard object:

```
// "MainStoryboard_iPhone" is your .storyboard file's name
// [NSBundle mainBundle] returns the main storyboard bundle.
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                                         bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Next, you instantiate the view that you want to present using that storyboard object:

```
// Give your view an identifier in the storyboard. That's how the storyboard object will find it. 
// You should see it in the right panel options when you click on the view.
UIViewController *dateRangeController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dateRange"];
```

Present.

```
[self presentViewController:dateRangeController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My mistake was in thinking that if you simply associated the view with the viewcontroller file (under the Class property in the config pane), that's all that was needed. But if you're using a storyboard, the UI process is expecting views to be instantiated through it, whether automagically or programmatically (presumably because more than one view can use the same view controller).

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the Storyboard object, instead you can use

`UIViewController *dateRangeController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dateRange"];`

Comment: Something I learned later :) Thanks for adding the info, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would disconnect the DatePickerViewController from the Nav controller and leave it as a stand alone VC.

Then get rid of showDateSelect and change clickedButtonAtIndex method to the following:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if( buttonIndex == 1 )
  {
    pickerView = [[DatePickerViewController alloc] init ];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pickerView animated:YES];
  }
}
```

Here you are pushing the pickerView unto the Navigation controller stack. You will need to pop it to remove it.

you can also experiment with present/dismiss but I am not sure whether it would work on Nav Controller stack.

Update:
I am not sure why you are re-declaring the viewDidLoad in your DatePickerViewController.h file. Take that out.

Also in all view Did/Will Load/Appear methods, you need to start by calling super. So insert [super viewDidLoad] as a first line in your viewDidLoad method of DatePickerViewController.m

Comment: This is still presenting me with the same black screen.

Comment: Noticed an error and updated. use self.navigationController instead of self to push.

Comment: Hm, same deal. I must be missing something more fundamental. I'm gonna add more to my original question.

Comment: Per your update: I actually completely deleted the two files. I've updated the main question with the new file contents. I still receive the black screen. No errors in the log.